# Distorted text on certain systems (gibberish) on a delphi 6 based program

Tags: windows-7, fonts, hebrew, delphi

Our company uses software which was developed in Delphi 6.

The main language is Hebrew (this problem began few years ago) -  in some systems we get gibberish values instead of Hebrew text.

This problem appears on certain systems like Windows 7 Enterprise or systems which were installed with image files like ghost or VM.

We tried using MUI installation for Hebrew and changed local settings without any success because it appears only on certain systems.

Is it an operating system problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Delphi 6 is not enabled for UNICODE. I believe UNICODE was introduced around Delphi 2009 or XE2, forget which. I write an application in Delphi 7 and what we need to do is to set the Windows locale in the code itself (I assume you already do this) and then set the "Languages for non-Unicode Programs" setting in Windows itself.

This is set as follows:

```
* Control Panel
* Clock, Language, and Region
* Region
* Administrative
* Language for non-Unicode programs
* Select Hebrew
* Reboot PC
```

This might resolve the issue for you. Note that switching between two non-Latin / UNICODE languages will be impossible for a non-UNICODE program. If you only need Hebrew, then you're OK. But if you need to dynamically switch between Hebrew and Russian, say, then you might have to look for another technique or upgrade to a UNICODE-enabled version of Delphi. Good luck!